# MediaScanner re-inserts photo into gallery & resets it's orientation and other fields

Tags: java, android, camera, gallery, media

My application creates photo and then inserts it into stock camera's bucket of gallery. (I want photos to be stored near other photos taken by standard camera)

Following code does this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN, taken_at);//msec
values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED, taken_at/1000);//sec
values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, taken_at/1000);//sec
values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE, fileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION, orientation);// << ORIENTATION
values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, dir+"/"+fileName);
uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
// WRITE JPEG BINARY DATA
```

When I select last two photos (one taken by stock camera, second - by my app) from MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, I get following:

```
fields:
_id, bucket_id, date_added, date_modified, datetaken, _display_name, 
orientation, title

fields values of photo taken by stock camera:
4471, 856031460, 1323942742, 1323942742, 1323942742189, 2011-12-15 15.52.22.jpg,
90, 2011-12-15 15.52.22.jpg

values of photo taken by my app:
4470, 856031460, 1323942722, 1323942722, 1323942722545, 2011-12-15 15.52.02.jpg     
90, 2011-12-15 15.52.02.jpg
```

So far, so good. It displays in gallery correctly. Problem appears when I remount sdcard and media scanner finishes his work:

```
stock camera's photo after re-mounting sdcard
1241, 856031460, 1323942742, 1323942742, 1323942742189, 2011-12-15 15.52.22.jpg
90, 2011-12-15 15.52.22.jpg

my app's photo after re-mounting sdcard
1242, 856031460, 1323943033, 1323942722, 1323942722000, 2011-12-15 15.52.02.jpg
0, 2011-12-15 15.52.02 
// WTF? orientation defaulted, date_added and date_modified were updated
```

It look like these photos are re-inserted, BUT NOW my app's photo is re-inserted with default values of fields(including orientation) while stock camera's photo values didn't change(excepting _id)!

Now my app's photos are displayed in gallery incorrectly (rotated, because orientation was reset), while stock camera's are OK.

How does media scanner recognize relation between record in media db and file it scans now? Looks like it can't do that in my case, removes old record, "linked to nonexistent file" and inserts new "never inserted before" record.

Any ideas, how to fix this?

PS: both photos are located in same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaScanner scans files in directories, and in case of photos, it scans photo's header, that contains EXIF tags, and takes ORIENTATION, DATE_TAKEN, DATE_MODIFIED tags from it. 
If this data is not equal to data in database then database data is replaced.

If you faced this problem, you need to update ORIENTATION exif tag manually with valid value.

Also I must mention that Android exif manager is very buggy and you might want to use org.apache.sanselan library that works great.